# Prism for Xamarin.Forms with Unity and CSLA

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, csla

I'm currently working on a Xamarin.Forms application using Prism and Unity as my IoC container.

I'm also attempting to add the business logic framework CSLA to my application.

There is a Xamarin sample provided here:

https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/blob/main/Samples/XamarinExample/XamarinExample/XamarinExample/App.xaml.cs

In particular, everything seems to be wired up using this piece of code:

```
public App()
{
      InitializeComponent();

      var services = new ServiceCollection();
      services.AddCsla();

      services.AddTransient(typeof(DataAccess.IPersonDal), typeof(DataAccess.PersonDal));
      serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
      ApplicationContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>();

      MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to fit that sort of code / registration into the Prism framework with Unity as the IoC container. Is this a time when I'd need to use the extensions? I saw those, but I was still coming up a little short on understanding what I should be doing.

I feel like there's a fundamental misunderstanding on my part of what I should be trying to achieve here, so any guidance on what direction I should be going in would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what I'm looking for:

```
   protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension() {
        var containerExtension = base.CreateContainerExtension();
    
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddCsla();
        
        var serviceProvider = ((UnityContainerExtension)containerExtension).Instance.BuildServiceProvider(services);

        ApplicationContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>();

        return containerExtension;
    }
```

Basically, it seems that I can override the container creation in my app.cs. From there I can call whatever methods I'd like against the ServiceCollection, build the container using the extension (in this case Unity) and return *that* container to the application.

Testing this in code I can see that I'm now able to inject the IDataPortalFactory into my view model along with the IServiceProvider, and the IServiceProvider is of type Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.

```
    public MainPageViewModel(
        INavigationService navigationService, 
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider, 
        IDataPortalFactory dataPortalFactory, 
        ITestClassFactory testClassFactory)
        : base(navigationService) {
        Title = "Main Page";

        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
        this.dataPortalFactory = dataPortalFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataPortalFactory));
        this.testClassFactory = testClassFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testClassFactory));
    }
```

So, if I'm getting IDataPortalFactory in my view model, I'm assuming my call to AddCsla() worked, and if the IServiceProvider is considered to be a Unity service provider, I must have successfully replaced the Service Provider implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dig into [`AddCsla()`](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/blob/6058cb27e7a0382bb1b09a8a0f97aedbff64d16d/Source/Csla/Configuration/ConfigurationExtensions.cs) and replicate all the registrations that are done in there.

The rest is easy:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(DataAccess.IPersonDal), typeof(DataAccess.PersonDal));
ApplicationContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>();
```

is trivial to translate to Unity

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<DataAccess.IPersonDal, DataAccess.PersonDal>();
ApplicationContext = unityContainer.Resolve<ApplicationContext>();
```

or Prism's "abstraction layer"

```
containerRegistry.Register<DataAccess.IPersonDal, DataAccess.PersonDal>();
ApplicationContext = containerRegistry.Resolve<ApplicationContext>();
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought it was possible to configure the DI subsystem in .NET to use another implementation, such as Unity? That way normal DI registrations work, just using that different implementation?

Comment: @RockfordLhotka interesting thought - I only know the other way round, i.e. using Microsoft DI with Prism (although that's experimental and not for production). In theory, Unity or DryIoc could perhaps implement `IServiceCollection` or provide an adapter.

Comment: To Rocky's point, I guess that's what I was assuming would be happening with Prism if it's using Unity as the IoC container. I was assuming (hoping?) that it was just replacing Microsoft's service collection / IoC container with Unity and that I just wasn't wiring up CSLA correctly, and that's why my CSLA related services were not being correctly injected into my view models, etc.

If it's not doing that then it would definitely make sense that I need to wire up CSLA manually by replacing the registrations that take place in AddCsla, or just figure out how to replace the container.

Comment: The comments you guys left gave me some inspiration on what I should google to find an answer. It lead me to this post:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1352